# UI Grid column filtering works very slow

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have used UI-Grid's built in cell filters but it takes hell lot of time to filter the data even when I have just 20 records.
`<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridCtrl.gridOptions1"`
`ui-grid-pagination`
 `ui-grid-pinning`
`ui-grid-resize-columns`
`ui-grid-move-columns`
 `ui-grid-selection`
`style="width: 100%; height:680px" class="ui-grid">`

and i have just enabled filtering as true.
Please help

Comment: It is hard to determine without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

actually I found the reason behind this.. I rendered all my rows at once with virtualization Threshold = number of rows, this does not allow the default ui grid rendering algorithm to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential workaround...

**1.** In ui-grid.js, remove the watches set up for each column filter in the header.  See if this removes the sluggishness. It will also make the grid not respond to filter changes. Continue to steps 2-4 to make the filters work again.

```
//$scope.col.filters.forEach(function (filter, i) {
//filterDeregisters.push($scope.$watch('col.filters[' + i + '].term', function(n, o) {
    //  if (n !== o) {
    //    uiGridCtrl.grid.api.core.raise.filterChanged();
    //    uiGridCtrl.grid.api.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
    //    uiGridCtrl.grid.queueGridRefresh();
    //  }
    //}));
 //});
```

**2.** In your code, create a function that iterates through the filter terms of each column and creates a string of all filter terms.

```
function getConcatenatedFilter() {
        var concatenatedFilter = "";
        var api = this.getGridApi();
        if (api) {
            for (var i = 0; i < api.grid.columns.length; i++) {
                concatenatedFilter += i + ":";
                var column = api.grid.columns[i];
                var term = column.filters[0].term || "";
                if (term) {
                    concatenatedFilter += term;
                }
            }
        }
        return concatenatedFilter;
    }
```

**3.** Create one watch that monitors the concatenated filter function above. When it fires, create a timeout to that sets another scope variable called `filtersCheck`.  The timeout will wait 200ms before changing `filtersCheck`.

```
 $scope.$watch(function() {return getConcatenatedFilter();},
         function (newVal: string, oldVal: string) {
            if (filterTextTimeout) {
                $timeout.cancel(filterTextTimeout);
            }
            var tempFiltersString = newVal;
            filterTextTimeout = $timeout(() => {
                $scope.filtersCheck = tempFiltersString;
            }, 200);
        });
```

**4.** Finally, set up a final watch for `filtersCheck` which will refresh the grid when it fires.

```
$scope.$watch('filtersCheck', (newVal, oldVal) => {
    if (newVal && oldVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
        gridApi.grid.queueGridRefresh();
    }
});
```

Comment: hi @James Lawruk, I have this issue but once `ui-grid-resize-columns` is removed it works faster any idea why resizing columns slows down filtration?